# Suppose $f: \{1,2,3,...,10\} \to \{1,2,3\} \times \{1,2,3\}$. Prove that f is not injective

Tags: functions

I have literally no idea how to approach this problem. Don't I need a specific function to work with?

Comment: Count the elements in $\{1,2,3,...,10\}$ and in $\ \{1,2,3\} \times \{1,2,3\}$. Conclude. This is called the "pigeon-hole principle".

Comment: Oh ok! Well, the second one has only 9 "slots". So at least one of the 10 elements in A has to map to a repeated element in B?

Comment: Indeed. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Answer (score 0):

We have $f : A \to B$ with
$$
A = \{ 1, \dotsc, 10 \} \\
B = \{ 1, 2, 3 \}^2
$$
As $B$ has only $9$ elements, but we have to choose values for $10$ different arguments, it is clear that at least one value has to be assigned twice for two different arguments.
Unfortunately this violates injectivity.

Answer (score 0):

You may think that you have $10$ pigeons and $9$ holes, [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle) says that **at least** one hole has more than one Pigeon.